# get parent $index inside child repeater angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 ng-repeat and I want to get parent ng-repeat ‍‍‍`$index` into child repeater.
My code below, the ng-click `track($index)` supposed to be the parent `$index`. Thanks for your help.

```
<tr ng-repeat="dataName in dataNames">
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name[$index]">
           <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="namesub in namesubs" ng-click="track($index)">{{namesub.textname}}</li>
           </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use key, value options like `ng-repeat="(pIndex, dataName) in dataNames"`

```
<tr ng-repeat="(pIndex, dataName) in dataNames">
<td>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name[$index]">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="namesub in namesubs" ng-click="track(pIndex)">{{namesub.textname}}</li>
      </ul>
</td></tr>
```